# How to track changes made in the ERD in oracle designer

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, designer

I want to track all changes made in my ERD in oracle 10g designer.
Please suggest how to achieve it.

use case: An ERD was approved in design phase. Few changes were made by development team and now in Implementation phase I need to track what all changes were made from say 3-Jan-12 to 3-Mar-2012

To add here:
1. In my project versioning of ER is not being used so ER Version diff is not an option for me.
2. In Reports, there are options for getting all entities, attributes which are created/modified in a period. But it seems it is not giving me correct results.

Comment: Which version of Designer are you using?

Comment: Designer Version is 10.1.2.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Designer 10g does support the SCM repository, which is the only real way of tracking changes to our models.  However, documentation is thin on the ground, probably as a matter of policy since Oracle pulled the plug on Designer as a tool with a future.

Oracle SCM is very powerful but not at all intuitive.  This should be obvious as we're working with rows of data rather than files like in most other source control scenarios.  Anyway, the upshot is, doing what you want to do won't be easy and you'll need resilience and persistence.  You might be able to find some old lags in [the ODTUG Designer forum](http://www.oaug.org/portal/page?_pageid=1015,10098607&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL#odtug) who still have some interest in the tool.

The other thing is, if you haven't already enabled the SCM you won't be able to retrieve the changes in the ERD over the last three months except through data mining.